# Google App Engine: "GET /_ah/start HTTP/1.1" 500

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, google-cloud-platform, http-status-code-500

I have a Google App Engine python apps deployed without problems. I changed some logging and redeployed, two things happened:

1. The endpoint keep returning `"GET /_ah/start HTTP/1.1" 500`
2. On GCP dashboard under App/Version I see that there are not instances on the latest version of my app. (I manually migrated the service on the last version of working in the image below)

[image]

This looks like they are having internal problems Google Cloud, or I am doing something wrong? Is there a way to manually allocate instance on the latest version of my GAE? It should be automatic to my understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Automatically migrating the traffic to a newly deployed version depends on the options used for deployment. From [gcloud app deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--promote):

> ```
> --promote
> ```
>
> Promote the deployed version to receive all traffic. Overrides the
>   default `app/promote_by_default` property value for this command
>   invocation. Use `--no-promote` to disable.