# How to handle ah/start with python GAE app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I had to change the scaling type on my GAE app to handle long-running requests.

But now the app has stopped responding, all I see are:

```
2021-04-09 01:22:59 default[20210409t011947]  "GET /_ah/start HTTP/1.1" 200
2021-04-09 01:22:59 default[20210409t011947]  "GET /_ah/start HTTP/1.1" 200
2021-04-09 01:23:00 default[20210409t011947]  "GET /_ah/start HTTP/1.1" 200
2021-04-09 01:23:00 default[20210409t011947]  "GET /_ah/start HTTP/1.1" 200
```

I understand [I have to respond to this startup event with some type of 200 response](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_types) which I am doing like this:

```py
@app.route('/_ah/start')
def startup():
    '''app starting'''
    logging.info('handle _ah/start')
    return {
        'status': 'OK',
        'msg': 'boot'
    }
```

But I never see that endpoint actually get called. Instead i just get the logs like I'm not responding to it.

After some digging I found [this message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56611547/google-app-engine-get-ah-start-http-1-1-500) talking about how maybe traffic wasn't getting switched over between instances and use `--promote` to switch but doesn't work.

The `main.py` has some logging that should come out at startup but I don't see anything.

Comment: can you share your app.yaml?

Comment: its fixed, tx. was to do with the URL config for the proxy

Answer (score 1):

turns out there was a front-end proxy intercepting the events!